# Dynamically created timepicker field not firing event

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I have a time field which is dynamically generated in an accordian. When the field is created with a different class name it's initialised. Now the drop down works where you can select the time but no event is fired.

Now when the page is loaded the first time, with the first timepicker field, the time is selected the event is fired no problem. The JS below checks for the class name which contains the word "time" as the class fields are named as follows:

The first one is time1 by default and the the dynamically generated field is named time2, time3 etc...

when the new field is generated in initiate it with the following code

```
$(".time"+hash).timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'HH:mm' });
```

`hash` is the number which is generated when the field is created

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[class*=time]').timepicker({
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        change: function(time) {
            // the input field
            var element = $(this), text;
            // get access to this Timepicker instance
            var timepicker = element.timepicker();
            var inputFieldId = element.attr('id');
            var sectionName = element.closest('.tab').children().attr('class');
            console.log(sectionName);
            text = timepicker.format(time);
            var message_tag = element.attr('data-id');
            ValidateSingleField(sectionName, inputFieldId, 'checkTime', event_form_messages[message_tag]);
        }
    });
});
```

I believe the onchange event is fired when a time is selected, this is true when the first timepicker field is loaded. But with the dynamically generated fields, nothing is fired.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You haven't included the `change` property in the first `timepicker()` call on the dynamic elements...

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, that was it